# Tradingview JS API to get processed data from its users custom indicators

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api

The tradingview doesn't support my country stock market and local brokers are using a tradingview library that contains some old technical indicators and there is no option to add custom indicators of tradingview's users. So, how can I use those custom indicators in a self-hosted charting library?. Well, there is some historical data that I want to send it to the tradingview using js api and get processed data which is produced by a custom indicator and finally draw the chart included with the indicator.

Or, Is there any way to use pine script for offline? Something like using pine script in a chart using Tampermonkey?

Any help or direction will be great.